# Reading comma seperater csv files with commas in cells in Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

What would be the best library or method to parse comma separated csv file having commas in their string cells in node js?

Comment: `csv-parser` works great.

Comment: I would suggest papaparse. https://www.papaparse.com/ . I even like the name

Answer (score 0):

[Papa Parse](https://www.papaparse.com/docs) is a really nice library, it works both in browser and in Node.js

Parsing is really simple, and the API is easy to understand.

You can configure parsing options with the options parameter, I've set header to true to pick up the header information from the CSV data.

The result includes the parsed data in the .data property and metadata in the .meta property.

For example:

```js
const csv = 
`Name,DOB,Title
Bob Jones,9/1/1980,Developer
Gina Smith,1/5/1985,"Project Lead"
Jane Walsh,3/7/1997,Coordinator`;

const options = { header: true };
const result = Papa.parse(csv, options);

console.log("CSV input:", `\n${csv}\n\n`);
console.log("Parsed output:", result.data);
console.log("Parsed output (metadata):", result.meta);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/PapaParse/5.2.0/papaparse.min.js"></script>
```